# MVC architeture with EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, architecture

I'm trying to understand how to separate the model class / MVC to interact with the database design in EF CodeFirst.

For example, considerate this simple architecture:

MyApp:

```
1. WEB 
2. DATABASE 
3. ModelEntity
```

The questions is:

Who should call the database without show tables in WEB UI?

The ModelEntity or model/MVC?

Is it necessary to use mapper in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller will be your middle man between the web ui and models, which represent tables in your database.

Normally, you web UI will use ViewModles, which may not be consistent with your ModelEntity, and that's when a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually have mine separated out:

1) Data layer: entity models, EF mappers, EF contexts

2) Domain layer: domain models, entity to domain model mappers, query objects, query handlers, command objects, command handlers, services

3) Application layer: view models, domain to view model mappers, application facades

4) UI layer: controllers, razor views, maybe some other view models that didn't fit into the application layer